# Should I reuse a Realm DB instance?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm wanting to use Realm DB in my Android/Java project, and have one question: is there any reason why I shouldn't create only a single Realm instance and keep it for the Application lifetime. I'm using Dagger2, and could create the Realm instance once and pass it around. Would that be a bad thing?

I have seen in (here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances) that it talks about keeping the instance for the activity lifetime. But I'm wondering if that could be extended to the application?

Is there any 'error state' that it can get into that could cause problems or that I would have to check for?

Are there any other advantages or disadvantages over short-lived instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a singleton Realm instance and reuse that everywhere. The reason is that Realm instances are thread singletons. You can read more about our threading model here: https://realm.io/news/threading-deep-dive/

If you want you could inject the configuration instead and use `Realm.getInstance(config)`, that will enable you to have a configuration for debug and one for release. If not, just using `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` would work just a well.

Comment: If I could make sure it always ran on the same thread using a scheduler, would that work. Or is it just not worth it?